# Is there a way to restart a party from the begining?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

After downloading Animal Crossing on my mobile, the problem is that I made bad choices and I would like to start my game again from the beggining but I do not know how.
 I uninstall and reinstall the game nothing to do as soon as I put my Nintendo account, it gives me back my old part. 
Is there a way to start again? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

From within the game:

- Select More
- Select Settings
- Select Nintendo Account Management
- Select Delete account link and save data
- Delete your save data